# FB.ui feed in Fan Page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, fb.ui

I'm trying to post a feed in facebook wall, but in fan page where I am an admin (instead of a personal page).

What is the right way to do this?  When I access fb using `fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed` , facebook logs in to my personal account and does not appear to log into the other pages that I am admin on.

I saw "Publishing to a Page", which seems like the correct API to request permission to publish to another page, is this the right path?

My code works for the personal page is:

```
<h1>feed</h1>
<p>
Publishing to the stream is easy, as all the fields are optional. Just     specify
what you need, and leave the rest out.
</p>

<script>
var publish = {
method: 'feed',
message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
name: 'Connect',
caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
description: (
  'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
  'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
  'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
 ),
  link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/',
 picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg',
 actions: [
 { name: 'fbrell', link: 'http://www.fbrell.com/' }
 ],
  user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about RELL'
  };

  FB.ui(publish, Log.info.bind('feed callback'));
  </script>
```

What do I need to do differently to post in fan page where I am admin?

Thank you.

Comment: I would add the javascript tag to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working example of publishing to a page you admin - http://www.fbrell.com/Graph%20API/4%20-%20Page%20Admin

Basically you should be using graph API at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

```
POST /v2.3/{page-id}/feed HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

message=This+is+a+test+message
```